# What are the possibilities to connect intenet from stolen iphone?

Tags: icloud, iphone

My iphone has been stolen,
I have configured touch id already.
After stolen i have put it in lost mode
so now what are the possibilities that thief can connect my
iphone to internet as he/she can not know passcode ?

So if thief can not connect to internet then how can i get location from find my iphone App ?

Answer (score 1):

Your stolen / locked iPhone can get an internet connection if :

1. A / your SIM card without pin is installed;
2. A know wifi network is in the area and if the "Ask to join network" feature is disabled;
3. Your SIM card is still inside and the guy don't turn off your phone